# Why does powershell Regex.Replace swallows newline?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have this script that does some regex replace on file. What I don't understand is why the returned string has all its newline removed?

Sample file content (UTF-8, with CR-LF after each line):

```
hello
hello
hello
```

The script:

```
$content = Get-Content "c:\spikes\regexnewline\regexnewline.txt"
Set-Content "c:\spikes\regexnewline\regexnewline-2.txt" $content # test

$content = [regex]::Replace($content, "ll", "yy") #basic replace

Set-Content "c:\spikes\regexnewline\regexnewline-3.txt" $content
```

Of course, file `regexnewline-2.txt` is an exact copy of the input file. But how come `regexnewline-3.txt` has its content on one line only, with a single CR-LF at the end?

```
heyyo heyyo heyyo\CR\LF
```

Obviously I'm missing something here. Can anyone spot it?

BTW, I've tried to play with regex.Replace and use the overload with 4 arguments, specifying `RegexOptions`, [as documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475.aspx), but the script fails saying there's no 4-argument overload for this method. Is Powershell using a different version of the .Net framework?

Comment: @if you print `$content` to the command line just before putting it to the file, what do you see ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you see this is because $content is an array of string when you originally read from the file. You can see the type of any variable like so:

```
$content.GetType().FullName
```

Get-Content by default returns an array of strings where each element represents a line. When you pass that array to .NET's regex replace method, PowerShell doesn't see a method overload that takes a string array but does see one that takes a string, so it coerces your string array into a string.  You can see the same effect if you do this right after the Get-Content call:

```
"$content"
```

You can even modify how PowerShell concats the individual elements when it does this:

```
$OFS = ", "
"$content"
```

Rather than use .NET regex replace, try using PowerShell's `-replace` operator which also handle regexs:

```
$content = $content -replace 'll','yy'
```

Comment: Thx, you're my hero! Also, this is a simplified example. I use .Net's Regex because the real code uses a `MatchEvaluator` that is a bit complicated to put in a one-liner.

Comment: No problem. MatchEvaluator is very handy.

Comment: This answer has just relieved me after an hour of banging my head against a wall. I'll add that `Get-Content -Raw filename` will return a single string rather than an array of per-line strings.